# write json on directory php

Tags: php, json, wordpress

This sounds a little basic but I dont know how to do this,
I am able to write the json file but I need it to be stored in a specific directory.

```
               $theColor = array('color' => 'red');
               $fp = fopen('color.json', 'w');
               fwrite($fp, json_encode($theColor));
               fclose($fp);
```

Now I am able to write this but the file appears on the root. I am using wordpress. I need to transfer it to a specific folder or to my drive C:/

Any ideas>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following line:

```
$fp = fopen('color.json', 'w');
```

with

```
$fp = fopen('/path/to/directory/color.json', 'w');
```

Make sure you have the correct rights on `/path/to/directory/` though.

**Edit**
As asked in your comment. The code to download the file.

```
$data = "/path/to/directory/color.json";
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="color.json"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($data));
readfile($data);
exit;
```

This should give you the well known pop-up. If it does not, try to change the data variable first to `file_get_contents("/path/to/directory/color.json")`

Or as a function:

```
/**
 * This method sets generates the headers for a file download and sends the file. PHP is exited after this function
 *
 * @param string $fileName    The name of the file, as displayed in the download popup
 * @param string $data        The path to the file, or the contents of the file
 * @param string $contentType The content type of the file
 * @param bool $file          Whether or not $data is a the path to a file, or the file data.<br />
 *                            True means $data contains the path to the file<br />
 *                            False when $data is a the data as a string
 *
 * @return void Exits PHP
 */
function outputForDownload($fileName, $data, $contentType, $file = true)
{
    header("Content-Type: {$contentType}");
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    if ($file === true) {
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($data));
        readfile($data);
    } else {
        header('Content-Length: ' . mb_strlen($data));
        echo $data;
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: thanks its working.
Do you also know how to download the said file after saving. Assuming the file was saved from the server, I will download it to my local

Comment: See my edit, I also included the function I use for it